# How to access data points of MKPolygon?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm trying to access the data points of a MKPolygon. There is a (read-only) property of MKMultiPoint class. The doc states that this will return the 'array of points associated with the shape'. However, the return type is MKMapPoint. This is actually one single point of which I can read x and y values. Where are all the other data points? I guess I'm confusing things here. Any help?

Thanks, pawi

Comment: Aha! I think I found it myself after writing this post (as usual ;-): MKMapPoint point = region.points[i];

Comment: I don't believe this question should have been closed for being 'too localised', as this is a valid question about the iOS MKMapKit that is still relevant today.  I came here with exactly the same problem; the Apple documentation is not clear so Stack Overflow was the best source of info on this.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe a valid question is closed as being too specific.  I wish it wasn't closed, it sure could have helped me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it myself: MKMapPoint point = region.points[i];